# Google kubernetes exposed Elasticsearch service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm very new to Kubernetes GKE. Deployed Elasticsearch application in workload Kubernetes. Now i want to go configure the http load balancing, exposed service. Can someone tell me what is the things i need to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Usually after installing an app you need to expose it. See [nginx example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/)

In your case of elastic application command could be similar to this

```
kubectl expose pod some-elasticsearch --name some-elasticsearch-9200 --type LoadBalancer --port 9200 --protocol TCP
```

Through UI do this

> Menu > Kubernetes Engine > Workload > go inside your elastic pod >
> Expose > Port/target port/protocol/load balancer

To test

> Menu > Kubernetes Engine >  Services and ingress > endpoint
> [external_ip:9200] as an example

Comment: kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
quickstart-es-default-0   1/1     Running   0          3d23h

Comment: bala_ganesh@cloudshell:~ (pj-becfr-postgresql-qa)$ kubectl expose pod some-elasticsearch --name some-elasticsearch-9200 --type LoadBalancer --port 9200 --protocol TCP
Error from server (NotFound): pods "some-elasticsearch" not found

Comment: you have to expose pod that exists, kubectl get pods --all-namespaces # list all pods

Comment: bala_ganesh@cloudshell:~ $ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE        NAME                                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default          quickstart-es-default-0                                     1/1     Running   0          5d11h
elastic-system   elastic-operator-0                                          1/1     Running   0          5d11h
gitlab           gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-66dcf8fc67-h9g6h                1/1     Running   0          5d11h

Comment: @balaganesh try using  answer with your pod name i.e 

Create a service for a pod valid-pod, which serves on port 9200 with the name "frontend" [source](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_expose/)

`kubectl expose pod  valid-pod --name frontend --type LoadBalancer --port 9200 --protocol TCP`
From the output of kubectl get pods --all-namespaces  use the name field [source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/elasticsearch-docker#start-an-elasticsearch-instance)

Comment: bala_ganesh@cloudshell:~ (pj-becfr-test-dev)$ kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
quickstart-es-default-0         1/1     Running   0          14h
quickstart-kb-5bfb978db-jrvt9   1/1     Running   0          14h
bala_ganesh@cloudshell:~ (pj-becfr-test-dev)$

Comment: How to expose the service now ?

Comment: @balaganesh Try using this command in cloud shell `kubectl expose pod  quickstart-es-default-0 --name frontend --type LoadBalancer --port 9200 --protocol TCP` . A service is now named by frontend and is exposed on port 9200.